# PEGJS doesn't generation "module.exports" in the parser file

Tags: pegjs

I trying to generate parser file using this code below, however the final result file parser.js does not contain the export line in spite of I have included `exportVar:...` in the option.

Am I suppose to add it manually at the top of the file ?

```
const peg = require('pegjs');
const fs = require('fs');

const grammarAsString = fs.readFileSync('./grammar.pegjs').toString();

const option = {
  output: 'source',
  exportVar: 'module.exports',
};

const parserSourceCode = peg.generate(grammarAsString, option);
fs.writeFileSync('./parser.js', parserSourceCode);
```

Comment: Try messing with the `format` option which might have the variable baked in.

Comment: Thanks @JoshVoigts , it's working now by setting format to "commonjs"

Answer (score 1):

It has been solved by setting format option to "commonjs" this pass it to the parser.

```
const option = {
  output: 'source',
  format: 'commonjs',
};
const parserSourceCode = peg.generate(grammarAsString, option);
fs.writeFileSync('./parser.js', parserSourceCode);
```